# Whitespace characters in image filenames are not working

Tags: joomla-3.7, images, file-upload

My Joomla version is 3.7.2 and my problem is that category images do not render when the filename contains whitespace characters.

For example, an image name like: `Atlas Vandal Resistant  category Picture 1.jpg`

The file is uploaded to the folder, but when I retrieve it, it shows an invalid/broken image.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Could you please ensure you're using the latest version of Joomla (3.9.20) and let us know if you still have the same issue?

Comment: Please take our [tour] and perhaps tell us about yourself by editing your profile.  I have tried to improve the English in your question.  If I have damaged what you intended to explain, please re-edit your question to make it more accurate (I didn't really know if that was the whole filename). @Kirpal

Comment: *Of course you should update Joomla. But in the meantime: Can you try to access directly the image file from your browser to see it gets loaded, instead of loading it within Joomla? Open the inspector and get the url of the image that is not loaded and try to open it in your browser.

Comment: How does the Image URL looks in the website (use a developer extension in your browser to copy the url)? is it a live site where we can see the issue?

Comment: I would assume that the issue is that the `src` attribute's value is not wrapped in quotes, so the rendered html will be creating `src=Picture` and then a dangling attribute of `1.jpg`  instead of `src="Picture 1.jpg"`.  Can't be 100% sure with out more details.

Comment: A Browser, tested with Firefox, will add a %20 in place of the white space in the GET URL but the OP provides no detail on where it is breaking, just 'when I retrieve it'. Later versions of Joomla do a lot more checking when a  file is uploaded and generally replace the white space with an underscore or hyphen(apparently better for SEO) to prevent this sort of issue. Quoting doesn't appear to make a difference.